# Logging in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, logs, log-analysis

I'm building a web server which will be implemented using .NET Core

Do you have a recommendation for a logging tool/library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Log4Net or SeriLog both of them have great facilities for logging, But in addition, logging storage for processing is important too. For this purpose, I would recommend you use elastic-search which you can use Nest library in .Net core to communicate with it.

Comment: What's the difference between log4net and SeriLog? I heard more about log4net

Comment: try to read this article : https://blog.elmah.io/serilog-vs-log4net/

Comment: There's no problem logging directly to a DB using SeriLog right?

Comment: Not at all, both of them have powerful Appenders for Database (SqlServer, Mongo, Elastic)